# React Native: How to make interactive push notifications?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

On iOS, you can reply to text messages right from the push notification without opening the app. I want to do something similar in React Native, to have the user interact with a custom UI in a push notification without opening the app. At the moment I'm using `react-native-onesignal`, but I haven't found a way to get this functionality with OneSignal. Does anyone know how I can approach this?

Comment: Have you found an answer?